# Make an Ubuntu script for stored wifi data

Tags: command-line, wireless, bash, scripts, connection

I'm trying to make a script for reading stored connections. These connections are stored in:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
```

But I don't want all the info, only names and passwords.

I use this command to list all files without spaces:

```
ls -b1A /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
```

I use the cat command to grep only the data I want

```
cat MyWifi.nmconnection | grep -v -e ssid -e uuid | grep -e psk= -e id
id=WifiName
psk=WifiPass
```

I have a simple script that runs both commands but the problem occurs when a .nmconnection file has spaces.

```
    bash script.sh 
My\ Wifi\ Connection.nmconnection
MyWifi.nmconnection

lets cat and grep those files
cat: 'My\': No such file or directory
cat: 'Wifi\': No such file or directory
cat: Connection.nmconnection: No such file or directory
id=WifiName
psk=WifiPass
```

I tried many times with 'IFS=' but I can't get to the solution.

Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#list files with ls -b1A to get one file for each line
files=$(ls -b1A *.nmconnection)

#display it to see it's ok
echo "$files"

#friendly echo before starting to cat and grep
echo -e "\nlets cat and grep those files"

for f in $files
do
cat  $f | grep -v -e ssid -e uuid | grep -e psk= -e id

done
```

Comment: you just need to use recursive option. try `grep -r '^psk='`.

Comment: i tried it, and it works, but i get a lot of lines with errors between de data

`code`
lets cat and grep those files
cat: 'My\': No such file or directory
My Wifi Connection.nmconnection:psk=SpacedWifiPass
MyWifi.nmconnection:psk=WifiPass
cat: 'Wifi\': No such file or directory
My Wifi Connection.nmconnection:psk=SpacedWifiPass
MyWifi.nmconnection:psk=WifiPass
cat: Connection.nmconnection: No such file or directory
My Wifi Connection.nmconnection:psk=SpacedWifiPass
MyWifi.nmconnection:psk=WifiPass
My Wifi Connection.nmconnection:psk=SpacedWifiPass
`code`

Comment: that's error from `cat $f`, just use `grep -r ...` and stored it what dou you want.

Comment: thank you ! it helped a lot!

Comment: Your basic error is trying to do this with a **string** that is output by the `ls` command - you should use a **glob** to place the file names in an **array** `files=( /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/* )` and then loop over the **elements** as `for f in "${files[@]}"`.